# How to \includepdf without centering

Tags: vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass[portrait]{minimal}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[noinfo, pdftex, frame]{crop}

\begin{document}
% Restrict page range, and set arrangement of pages per sheet here.
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x1, noautoscale]{mypdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

mypdf.pdf is a pdf with a page size of 4" x 6".  It appears in the center of the new pdf, but I would like it to position at the top middle of the page.  Is this possible?   I have read the package docs for crop, geometry, and pdfpages and there does not seem to be an option for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `offset=0 190` to shift zero to the right and `190` vertically.  See documentation for `pdfpages` at https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

```
\documentclass[portrait]{minimal}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[noinfo, pdftex, frame]{crop}

\begin{document}
% Restrict page range, and set arrangement of pages per sheet here.
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x1, noautoscale,offset=0 190]{mypdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here was the original 4x6 document, `mypdf.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```